# Understanding the changes to react-router in v4

Tags: reactjs, react-router-v4

**Background**

I am following along with a course to learn `React.js`. It has been great and very helpful but I keep getting an error while working with `react-router`

From what I have read when I put the error into Google is that there is a change to `react-router` in version 4. My problem is worst cause I am trying to learn this and understand it at the same time so it makes it a bit more confusing.

**Error**

> warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked
>   as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
>       in Router (at index.js:12)

**Question**

Please shed some light on why this will not work in V4

```
<Router history={browserHistory}>

 "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.5.4",
    "react-dom": "^15.5.4",
    "react-router": "^4.1.1"
  },
```

**Example**

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={browserHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Home} />
        <Route path="/services" component={Services} />
        <Route path="/portfolio" component={Portfolio} />
        <Route path="/about" component={About} />
        <Route path="/contact" component={Contact} />
        <Route path="*" component={Fourofour} />
    </Router>

,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**Imports**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Router, Route, browserHistory } from 'react-router'
import Fourofour from './containers/fourofour/Fourofour';
import Home from './containers/home/Home';
import Services from './containers/services/Services';
import Portfolio from './containers/portfolio/Portfolio';
import About from './containers/about/About';
import Contact from './containers/contact/Contact';
```

Comment: What do you mean by "this will not work in V4"? It will work. The code will compile.

Comment: Hey thanks for your help. I am going off the error I have. If you have time would you mind looking at my current project? https://github.com/wuno/react-components

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router (at index.js:12)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<Route path="/" component={Home} />
```

to

```
<Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

and you might get better results. As you have it now, `/services` (and the other paths) will also match the `/` path.

More information about the `exact` keyword can be found at the [React Router V4 docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Route/exact-bool).

If you want to specify the history on the `<Router>` componenent, you need to manually create the history in your code (`<BrowswerRouter>` creates it for you so you don't need to specify a `history` prop for it). You can do this by creating a new file:

```
// utils/history.js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory({
  /* pass a configuration object here if needed */
});
```

And then wherever you need to use the history:

```
import history from './utils/history';

<Router history={history}>
...
```

You will also need to install the history package:

```
npm install history --save
```

The React Router V4 docs also have an [example of using a custom history](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Router/history-object).

Finally, if you are never using the history object, you could just use the [`<BrowserHistory>` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter) and it will manage the history for you without having to create a custom history object.

Comment: I have changed this but I get the same problem. 
warning.js:36 Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router (at index.js:12)

Comment: Yes thank you I am trying to figure out how to incorporate this into my project. But the problem I am facing is understanding why my current code does not work.

Comment: Your current code doesn't work because you did not create a history object. If you look carefully at my example above, I create the history object with `createBrowserHistory({...`. The link I provided to the React Router V4 docs shows pretty much the same thing.